How can I make VSCode act as a server to debug golang apps with delve when I run `dlv dap --client-addr=:2345` in the remote machine?
I'd expect to find an option in launch.json that would allow me to specify the port VSCode should listen to for connections so I can tell dlv to connect as a client to VSCode with its --client-addr parameter, but I can't find anything. Is it possible? Should I create a feature request for this?

Given the lack of answers, I'm going to assume this feature isn't available.
Here is the feature request I just created: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/3559
